# Read beyond end of file

Tags: delphi, grid

I'm trying to retrieve some information from a program made in Delphi. It happens that when I try to see a list, the following error occurs:

> Read beyond end of file

In debug mode, the code goes around this piece of code:

```pascal
assignfile(usersession.ftemp_eime,'D:\EIME_DATA\DATA\'+usersession.nome_fich);
rewrite(usersession.ftemp_eime);
assignfile(usersession.f_eime,'D:\EIME_DATA\equipamentos.xxi');
reset(usersession.f_eime);
//..... do work...
if not eof(usersession.f_eime) then
begin
  while not eof(usersession.f_eime) do
  begin
    read(usersession.f_eime,usersession.eime);
    usersession.passa:=true;

    if usersession.eime.estado=4 then usersession.passa:=false;

    if usersession.passa=true then
    begin
      usersession.eime.pos_temp:=(filepos(usersession.f_eime)-1);
      write(usersession.ftemp_eime,usersession.eime);
    end;
  end;    // while
end;

//FileMode :=fmOpenRead+fmShareDenyNone;
//..... End Work
closefile(usersession.f_eime);
usersession.tamfich:=filesize(usersession.ftemp_eime);
closefile(usersession.ftemp_eime);
```

In a normal situation, this would show a material list in a Grid.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using old Pascal style file I/O? Have you considered using `TFileStream` or `TStream(Reader|Writer)` instead?

Comment: I'm just trying to retrieve some information from an old platform and right now I'm having trouble querying the data due to this error

Comment: You didn't indicate which line of code is raising the error, or show what the file data looks like, or show what `usersession` looks like, etc. Please provide a [mcve]